# I am trying to use PassportJs with multiple types of users (each one has a different model). What am I doing wrong?

Tags: session, express, configuration, passport.js, multiple-users

I am trying to use PassportJs with express using multiple types of users (each one has a different model). 
When I use it with only one type of user it is OK but when I add a second one it is not working. Any idea ?

```
// Configuring Passport
var passport = require ('passport');

var LocalStrategyAdmin = require ('passport-local').Strategy;
var LocalStrategyClient = require ('passport-local').Strategy;

var adminModel = require ('./models/adminModel');
var clientModel = require ('./models/clientModel');

var session = require ('cookie-session');

app.use (session ({keys: [secretKey1, secretKey2]}));

app.use (passport.initialize ());
app.use (passport.session ());


passport.use (new LocalStrategyAdmin (adminModel.authenticate ()));
passport.use (new LocalStrategyClient (clientModel.authenticate ()));

passport.serializeUser (adminModel.serializeUser ());
passport.deserializeUser (adminModel.deserializeUser ());

passport.serializeUser (clientModel.serializeUser ());
passport.deserializeUser (clientModel.deserializeUser ());
```

I fixed it

1. I had to give distinct names for each local strategy
2. I had to serialize/deserialize depending on the type of the user (client or admin in my case).

Comment: Is the second strategy called in some time? I think the first is always handling the authentication process since both are LocalStrategy and there isn't a different name for each one. You should name it different.

Comment: can you post fixed version of code

Answer (score 2):

I had to give distinct names for each local strategy
I had to serialize/deserialize depending on the type of the user (client or admin in my case).

Answer (score 0):

you also want to use separate instances of passport

```
var Passport = require ('passport');
var passportAdmin = new Passport.Passport();
var passportClient = new Passport.Passport();
```