# How to have two different logins within my app using nodejs and passport?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

I am using mongodb, mongoose, express, passport (and its dependencies) here!

Basically, I have a functional login working for a "user" model, and I want to create another login which would be working for a "employee" model. The problem is,when i tried to create the "employee" login and authentication, I replicate what I did for the "user" one but it did not work. The app does not recognize that there is an employee logged in, like it does when i do login with an user. **When i do console.log isAuthenticated after doing the employee login, it says that is false, it means, that no one is logged in**... I am being able to register both users and employees well, the problem ins mainly after the login, where the user login works fine, and the employee login do not.

I don't want to create different roles, I want to create two different logins.

I am using the following models:

This one for the **user**

```
     var mongoose = require("mongoose");
    var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

    var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        username:String,
        password:String,
        isAdmin: {type:Boolean, default:false}
    })

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

This one for the **Employee**

```
      var mongoose = require("mongoose");
    var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");


    var EmployeeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        username:String,
        password:String,
        firstname:String,
        lastname:String,
        birth:String,
        adress:String,
        role:String,
        education:String,
        experience:String

    })

EmployeeSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
module.exports = mongoose.model("Employee", EmployeeSchema);
```

This is the code that I am using in the main app.js (the part that refers to passport config and login routes). The register routes both for user and employee are working fine. **Somehow I feel that the problem is in this part**, even though I don't know if it is just the way like I am coding this.

```
 **//PASSPORT CONFIGURATION**
    app.use(require("express-session")({
        secret: "secret",
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized:false
    }));
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    passport.use('user',new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
    passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
    passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
    passport.use('employee',new LocalStrategy(Employee.authenticate()));
    passport.serializeUser(Employee.serializeUser());
    passport.deserializeUser(Employee.deserializeUser());
```

This is the post route for **user login**

```
     app.post("/login", passport.authenticate("user",{successRedirect:"/",failureRedirect:"/login"}),function(req,res){
 })
```

This is the post route for the **employee login**

```
app.post("/employeelogin", passport.authenticate("employee",{successRedirect:"/",failureRedirect:"/employeelogin"}),function(req,res){
})
```

Sorry if this is too long... any help is appreciated! I have been though this for 3 days, doin console.logs to try to solve this, but I have not found how to work it out yet.
Thank you for your attention!

PS: I have see this thread here: [two different login with node-passport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35816417/two-different-login-with-node-passport)
but I did not get properly what he is trying to do

Comment: Possible duplicate of [passport.js with multiple authentication providers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20745296/passport-js-with-multiple-authentication-providers)

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35751214/i-am-trying-to-use-passportjs-with-multiple-types-of-users-each-one-has-a-diffe) is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Can you set the login type in headers and based on the value initialise passport for the request dynamically.

Comment: When I call a console.log(req.user) inside of the post route for the employee login, it gives me the profile which I am logged in (which is nie and expected), but, after "being logged in", if I run console.log(req.user) again, it says that it is undefined. The same does not happen if I login using the login user, which when I run the console.log(req.user) it always give me the profile which i am logged in. Do you guys know how to solve it?